# "you have already raised this type of flag"

Tags: support, flagging

Does that mean I already raised it on this particular post but forgot, or that I've used up my day's ration of this type of flag?
… or something else?

I've seen it twice today, but wasn't paying close enough attention to what may have caused it. I certainly didn't think I'd raised enough flags for the system to limit me.

Comment: Can you add a link to the involved question/answer if you see the message again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug. Generally, the error message is meant to show if you've flagged the post before, but a bug caused this to break. [This is now fixed.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248107/222623)

Comment: Aha - nice find. Thought it felt like a bug, but once I'd really spotted what happened, I never saw it again that day to test the theory.

Answer (score 1):

Without details, I would trust that you actually flagged that specific post already.

The message for "go away" due to no flags left is different.

However, if the code burps, you could get these when the conditions are not present. Hard to say for sure unless it continues.

Comment: I'd guessed it may have been a hiccup. I was trying to look back through the queues & find which one it was, but no joy. Re patrix's comment, I'll link if I see one again.